# Unable to upload large file 300 MB at Amazon S3. Response is "Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload large file upto 300 MB, but every time I am getting "Internal Server Error". I am using:

```
try {
$uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
->setClient($s3Client)
->setSource($fileloc)
->setBucket($buketname)
->setKey($filename)
->setConcurrency(3)
->setOption('ACL', $fileacl)
->setOption('Metadata', array('Agent' => 'aisS3Client'))
->setOption('CacheControl', 'max-age=3600')
->build();
// Perform the upload. Abort the upload if something goes wrong
try {
$uploader->upload();
//echo "File Uploaded : ".$filename;
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
$uploader->abort();
//echo "File Did not Uploaded : ".$filename;
}
} catch (\Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does error the same if you try to upload less then 300mb file?

Comment: @sergio Its working fine with file size >160 MB

Comment: "Internal Server Error" is ***always*** an invitation to look into the error logs. In these, the real error message is written. Asking about "Internal Server Error" as the only error description is not directed towards concrete results then. Instead look for the more concrete error description within the server and php logs.

Comment: @hakre - how would they be meant to look at the Amazon server error logs?

Comment: Well if it's about the remote system and if you don't have the logs at hand from that remote system, you need to go through a proxy to obtain the logs. For a system like Amazon, I guess this is first of all the support resources and next to that standard technical support. There perhaps is a request ID with which it is possible to ask for more information (if the case of error handling internal server errors isn't fully documented yet).

Comment: @Danack: Exemplary AWS 500 Internal Server Error: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=313830 - As you can see within the response, there is a request-ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to upload a 300MB file in one go is a bad idea.

You could use the setMultipartUploadSize method to have the S3Client split it into chunks. However it would also be even simpler just to use the putObject() method which takes care of that for you.